# Wouldn't it be better to use a soft approach with newbies on this SE?

Tags: discussion

Say someone saw Buddhism.Stackexchange yesterday and joined in, Then that means that this particular person is not interested in the laws or policies here.
He or she has a question and that question will be asked in his/her own Form,words,grammar knowledge & softness or harshness.

If we are able to answer the question and the next day this person login he sees a bunch of answers and some *Rep* to his profile he will be exited and the he will come again. After this we can slowly lay the rules and regulations on him.

---

We can take the time to edit the question according to the policies and make it suitable. And by the way giving a thumbs up for a new user and encouraging him or her is a great thing to do but for some reason people are very picky on that too, I mean come on we are not reviving movies on Oscars. It is just a new user with his or her own little question, if we are able to show both verbal and emotional feedback with answers and up votes/stars it will help the new user to be more open next time.

Comment: I remember it used to be "softer" before. I guess it hasn't been for a while, thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: This topic could be more actionable or more informative if it were more specific. I'd like to ask you to answer this by posting answers -- these answers could link to specific questions which were treated too-hardly, with one or more suggestions of how to edit the question instead.

Comment: It's already policy to welcome and to edit instead of close where possible. Sorry if that's not happening enough. I'm conscious of having closed (instead of editing) two types of question: a) exact duplicates b) religious comparisons, which require answers to express some opinion about other religions. With the former (exact duplicates), I hope I'm doing the OP a favour by linking to where the question has already been asked, and where they can immediately find many good answers.

Comment: The latter (over-broad religious comparisons/opinions) is in the class of question which we should edit if possible to make it more on-topic (i.e. a question that's more about Buddhism than other religions). However even more important than editing, IMO, is to not change the OP's intent. If I don't see how to edit without asking a completely different question instead, which wasn't what the user was asking, then I prefer to close it to give the OP has an opportunity to discuss and/or edit it (instead of making an edit they wouldn't like).

Comment: There may be other examples that I don't remember at the moment, but these are the two I remember.

Comment: Thank you for the extended explanation Chris. I did not tried to sound negative, i was just giving a suggestion. @ChrisW

Answer (score 1):

One thing we can do is to see if the user is active in other SE / SO sites and in case not be more lenient and provide extra guidance as they will have no clue on how the site operates.